# Python: Add data to first CSV column

Tags: python, csv

Using Python v2.7.4:

I have the following CSV file:

```
Item Number,Item Description,List Price,QTY Available
2000-000-000-380,AC - CF/M Series Green For White Hood,299.99,3
2000-000-000-400,AC - CF/M Series Orange For Black Hood,299.99,3
2000-000-000-480,AC - CF/M Series Orange For White Hood,299.99,3
```

I have been trying to change the file to:

```
Fulfillment,SKU,Qty
US,2000-000-300,3
US,2000-000-380,3
US,2000-000-400,3
```

So far I have the following code:

```
import csv
import os

inputFileName = "temp_modified.csv"
outputFileName = os.path.splitext(inputFileName)[0] + "_pro.csv"

with open(inputFileName, "rb") as inFile, open(outputFileName, "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.reader(inFile)    
    w = csv.writer(outfile)

    r.next()    
    w.writerow(['Fulfillment', 'SKU', 'Qty'])

    for row in r:
        w.writerow((row[0], row[3]))
```

With this code I get the following output:

```
Fulfillment,SKU,Qty
2000-000-000-380,3
2000-000-000-400,3
2000-000-000-480,3
```

How do I insert US to the beginning column? (Just for reference there is more than just 3 rows in these csv files but for space I left out the rest.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a literal string to your row:

```
for row in r:
    w.writerow(('US', row[0], row[3]))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be doing a lot of `csv` manipulation, I strongly recommend looking at the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library.  It makes a lot of things much simpler.  Your code would become something like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("temp_modified.csv")
df["Fulfillment"] = "US"
df = df.rename_axis({"Item Number": "SKU", "QTY Available": "QTY"})
df = df[["Fulfillment", "SKU", "QTY"]]
df.to_csv("temp_modified_pro.csv", index=False)
```

---

Some explanation follows.  First, read in the csv file into an object called a `DataFrame`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("temp_modified.csv")
>>> df
        Item Number                        Item Description  List Price  \
0  2000-000-000-380   AC - CF/M Series Green For White Hood      299.99   
1  2000-000-000-400  AC - CF/M Series Orange For Black Hood      299.99   
2  2000-000-000-480  AC - CF/M Series Orange For White Hood      299.99   

   QTY Available  
0              3  
1              3  
2              3
```

Then add a column called "Fulfillment":

```
>>> df["Fulfillment"] = "US"
>>> df
        Item Number                        Item Description  List Price  \
0  2000-000-000-380   AC - CF/M Series Green For White Hood      299.99   
1  2000-000-000-400  AC - CF/M Series Orange For Black Hood      299.99   
2  2000-000-000-480  AC - CF/M Series Orange For White Hood      299.99   

   QTY Available Fulfillment  
0              3          US  
1              3          US  
2              3          US
```

Then rename the axes:

```
>>> df = df.rename_axis({"Item Number": "SKU", "QTY Available": "QTY"})
>>> df
                SKU                        Item Description  List Price  QTY  \
0  2000-000-000-380   AC - CF/M Series Green For White Hood      299.99    3   
1  2000-000-000-400  AC - CF/M Series Orange For Black Hood      299.99    3   
2  2000-000-000-480  AC - CF/M Series Orange For White Hood      299.99    3   

  Fulfillment  
0          US  
1          US  
2          US
```

Select the columns you want:

```
>>> df = df[["Fulfillment", "SKU", "QTY"]]
>>> df
  Fulfillment               SKU  QTY
0          US  2000-000-000-380    3
1          US  2000-000-000-400    3
2          US  2000-000-000-480    3
```

And finally write it out to a csv, without including an extra index column (the numbers on the left, the row labels):

```
>>> df.to_csv("temp_modified_pro.csv", index=False)
>>> !cat temp_modified_pro.csv
Fulfillment,SKU,QTY
US,2000-000-000-380,3
US,2000-000-000-400,3
US,2000-000-000-480,3
```

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely look into that library.